# Absolute Convergence Maclaurin Series using the first three non zeros

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find the first three nonzero terms of the Maclaurin series (so generated at $x=0$) and the values of x for which the series converges absolutely

$$f(x)=\frac {x^3}{1+2x}$$

So I found the first 3 nonzeros which are $f'''(0)=6$, $f^4(0)=-48$, and $f^5(0)=480$

So $$f(x)={x^3}-{2x^4}+{4x^5}-{8x^6}+{16x^7}$$ I added a few more terms to help the pattern.

How do I find the series from this and find the values of x for which the series converges absolutely? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The solution in three steps as shown above

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really need to improve on my power series on how to for them

Comment: you are Welcome.